# C++11 value-initialization with defaulted default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

In the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int z;
    A(std::string) {}
    A() = default;
};

int main() {
    char buf[1000];
    std::fill(buf, buf + 1000, 'x');
    auto a = new(buf) A{};
    std::cerr << "A.z: " << a->z << std::endl;
}
```

Compiled with GCC 4.8 [outputs zero](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=63821c4c618f352a) (same behavior with Clang 3.4).  This seems to indicate that `a` is being zero-initialized before the default constructor is called.

But according to [value-initialization rules on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), the object should not be initialized before the default constructor invocation.  Class `A` qualifies for bullet point #1 under C++11:

> 1) If T is a class type with at least one user-provided constructor of any kind, the default constructor is called.

Another perhaps useful data point is that if we replace `A() = default` with `A() {}` in the above example, [no zero-initialization happens](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=962fdf6ff098d460) as expected.  This seems to indicate that bullet point #2 of value initialization is being followed in the initial example which would be wrong:

> 2) If T is an non-union class type without any user-provided constructors, then the object is zero-initialized and then the implicitly-declared default constructor is called (unless it's trivial)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wording that you cite for value initialization in C++11 was considered defective, see [Core Working Group DR 1368](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1368) and the resolution in [Core Working Group DR 1301](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301) that changed the wording (showing additions with **bold** and deletions with <strike>strike through</strike>):

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9 [class]) with **either no default constructor (12.1 [class.ctor]) or** a **default constructor that is** user-provided **or deleted** <strike>constructor (12.1 [class.ctor])</strike>, then the **object is default-initialized** <strike>default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor)</strike>;
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided **or deleted default** constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if <strike>T's implicitly-declared default constructor is</strike> **`T` has a** non-trivial **default constructor**, <strike>that constructor is called.</strike> **default-initialized**;

Some compilers - I believe GCC 4.8 and clang since 3.3ish - have already implemented the resolution of DR 1301.